# Find the polynomial of degree 10 that interpolates the function arctan(x) at 11 equally spaced points in the interval [1,6]

Tags: matlab

So this question is more specifically based off of Newtons form but I'm having trouble writing the script. How would you approach writing this, what I have so far is

length=abs(c-d);

m=length/11;

for k=c:m:d;

```
fk=func(k);
```

end

But I can't figure out how to store all the values into vector so I can run Newtons polynomial interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use `length` as a variable name because there is a pre-defined function named `length`.
2. If you divide the length by 11 and do c:m:d, you create 12 equally-spaced points. Divide it by 10.
3. When you do c:m:d, you need to make sure `c<d`.

This is just a simple linear regression problem. You can either manually solve the problem by creating a 11x11 matrix, or you can just use `polyfit`.

```
X = c:m:d;
Y = atan(X);
C = polyfit(X,Y,10);
```

Is the easiest solution, but if you want to know what's happening, you can do this.

```
A = [X.^10,X.^9,X.^8,X.^7,X.^6,X.^5,X.^4,X.^3,X.^2,X.^1,X,ones(11,1)];
C = A\Y;
```

You will get the same coefficient vector `C`. Your desired polynomial is like this

```
y = C(1)*x^10 + C(2)*x^9 + ......+ C(10)*x + C(11)
```

Comment: Also, it is easier to create `X` using `linspace(c,d,N)` where `N` is the number of points you want. Then it doesn't even matter if `c>d`.